# Extract values from a list of objects in javascript using underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have a list of objects, where each object has numerical values:

```
var cpuInfo = [
  { user: 189625143,
    nice: 0,
    sys: 40239022,
    idle: 2087123838,
    irq: 720490 },
  { user: 76627160,
    nice: 0,
    sys: 35444113,
    idle: 2204916386,
    irq: 18233303 }
]
```

I need to calculate the value of `idle` divided by the sum of all values.

For that, I need to get the sum of all of the values in all of the objects.

I've tried doing this to extract just the values:

```
_(cpuInfo).each(_.values)
```

I expected it to return a list like so:

```
[189625143, 0, 40239022, 2087123838, 720490, 76627160, 0, 35444113, 2204916386, 18233303]
```

But for some reason it returns the exact same thing I started out with - a list of objects.
Even if I expand it to this:

```
_(cpuInfo).each(function(item) { return _(item).values() })
```

It still returns just the list of objects.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var res = _.map(cpuInfo, function (el) {
  return _.values(el)  
})
res = _.flatten(res)

console.log(res);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/rodipu/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

In pure JavaScript

```
temp = [];
cpuInfo.forEach(function(obj){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
        temp.push(obj[k]);
    });
});
```

Ref - [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Note - *both functions compatible with >IE8*